# jquery hover selector - another way

Tags: jquery, hover, selector, lavalamp

I have a set of menu like this:

```
<ul class="lavalamp">
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>
        Menu 3
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu 1</li>
            <li>Sub Menu 2</li>
            <li>Sub Menu 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>
```

I add a lavalamp effect on this. When I hover over any menu, the lavalamp background moves onto the hovered menu and it will move back to current menu if menu is not hovered.

The problem is, when I hover into the sub menus, it is considered not hovering the menu so the lavalamp background move back to the current menu item. To prevent this, I add a hover selector in my jquery.lavalamp.js like this:

```
$li.not(".back").hover(function() {
    if (!$('.sub-menu').is(":hover")) {
    move(this);
    }
}, function(){});

function move(el) {
    $back.each(function() {
        $(this).dequeue(); }
    ).animate({
        width: el.offsetWidth,
        left: el.offsetLeft
    }, o.speed, o.fx);
};
```

while move(this) is the function to move the lavalamp background to the hovered menu. It works well in every browser except in IE. The lavalamp background won't move and there is a javascript error called "unsupported pseudo :hover". I have searched in jquery site and it doesn't have a selector called :hover.

Are there any other way to replace the :hover selector above? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might try mouseenter/mouseleave.

Comment: .is(":hover") is works perfectly :http://jsfiddle.net/AyAZx/5/

Comment: :hover is a css pseudo selector, and its not completely supported in all IE versions. Read more at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: @CaptainCarl the OP is using `hover`, which maps to those two. That's not what they're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as `:hover` is notoriously difficult to infer statically via scripting (and older IEs don't support the pseudo class on anything other than `<a>`s), it's better to use the jQuery `hover()` method to force a *real* class and use that instead:

```
$li.hover(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Then you replace your second line,

```
if (!$('.sub-menu').is(":hover")) {
```

...with this:

```
if(!$(this).closest('.hover').length){
```

...which instead tests to see if a jQuery object looking for ancestors with the `hover` class returns any elements.

Answer (score 0):

use  this code, it me help you:

```
var previousClass = '';
var arr= $("li");
$.map(arr, function(li){
 li.mouseout(function (li) {
                    eventMouseOut(li);
                });
 li.mouseover(function (li) {
                    eventMouseOver(li);
               });
});
 function eventMouseOver(_this) {
            previousClass = $(_this).attr("class");
            $(_this).removeClass().addClass("Hover");
        }
 function eventMouseOut(_this) {

            var count = 1;
           var arr= $("li");
            $.map(arr, function (li) {
                $(li).removeClass().addClass("Normal");
                count++;
            });
        }
```